# How do you debug Windows Authentication in Visual Studio 2013 and IIS Express?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

I am currently developing an ASP.NET MVC website using Windows Authentication. However for some reason the authentication process fails each time, I have to manually type in the credentials.

My scenario is as follows:

- My current Windows user (User_A) is member of "Group_A" in AD. User_B is member of the "Group_B" group.
- The required security group to gain access to the site is "Group A", restricted using the Authorize action filter.

I now run the site and tries to gain access to it. It succeeds without asking for credentials. I now try to change the required group to "Group_B", which my current Windows user does not have access to. As expected the credentials popup appears. However even if I enter the credentials for "User_B" the credentials popup continually appears, without granting access.

My Web.config is as follows:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <windowsAuthentication>
          <providers>
            <remove value="Negotiate" />
          </providers>
        </windowsAuthentication>
      </authentication>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

From my applicationHost.config:

```
<sectionGroup name="security">
    <section name="access" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
    <section name="applicationDependencies" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
    <sectionGroup name="authentication">
        <section name="anonymousAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        <section name="basicAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="clientCertificateMappingAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="digestAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="authorization" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="ipSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
    <section name="dynamicIpSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
    <section name="isapiCgiRestriction" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
    <section name="requestFiltering" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
</sectionGroup>
```

My MVC controller is:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Middleware_admin")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

From the F4 properties window:

[image: F4 properties]

Just to verify. Yes, I have checked multiple times that I provide the correct credentials.

If you cannot spot the mistake I made, is there a way I can manually debug on the authorization process? A way to check if it is the authentication or authorization that fails?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For typical authentication/authorization testing you should switch to full IIS. The design of IIS Express can lead to many issues in these areas.

Comment: are you logging the users out of windows then back in after you make the change?